# How do you capture the output message from a successful MERGE statement when using it in a procedure?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, plsql

Sorry if this sounds like a rather simple question..

When using the console, normally the statement outputs something similar to

`X records merged`

How do I capture this output into an out variable when using a merge statement in a procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SQL%ROWCOUNT`. This return rows processed in last sql statement
For example:

```
declare
res number;
begin
select 0 into res from dual;
dbms_output.put_line(sql%rowcount || ' rows selected');
end
```

This code prints `1 rows selected` because you selected one row. I hope this helps